# How to light-up a sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone

I've already know how to dark-down a CCSprite object by:

sprite.color = ccc3(x, x, x); // x is a value less then 255

(As far as i know, it should be a direct mapping of openGL functions, so its easy to achieve.)

But when it comes to light-up, my current solution is adding another mask sprite (same shape but all in white), changing its blendFunc to { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE } and overlaying it onto the target. Besides all the codes added, there should be a mask image for each need-to-light-up one.

Is there a way to do light-up as easily as dark-down?

Answer (score 0):

However, not as easy as setColor, in Cocos2d 2.x, with OpenGL ES 2.0 support, you can achieve this by using custom shaders. You can get started here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x

You may also try inverting the sprite's darker color to get a lighter one.